# count occurrence of word in a file in shell without using command

Tags: shell

Below is my code but its not giving output as i want.
i want to print  word and their occurrence number like:
anish 3
manish 4

```
 echo -n "ENTER FILE NAME:"
    read file
    while read -r -a word <$file; do
    if [ $# -ne 1 ] 
    then
        for word in $line; do
         # echo " $word = ${#word[*]}"

p=0    
                done


echo "$word = ${#word[*]}"


 fi

break


done
```

Comment: without using command ....... cool!

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "command"? If you are refering to "external program", I think you shouldn't then use `[ $# -ne 1 ]`. While `[` is indeed a builtin command in some shells, it is an external command in Posix shell, and from your tag, I conclude that you are looking for a Posix-compliant solution.

Comment: let's forget [ $# -ne 1 ] this is not need here then what should i do?

Answer (score 0):

If you can use a more capable shell, like bash, you can do:

```
$ declare -A words    # an associative array, not POSIX

$ while read word; do let "words[$word]++"; done <<END
anish
manish
anish
manish
anish
END

$ for key in "${!words[@]}"; do echo "$key ${words[$key]}"; done
manish 2
anish 3
```